# What does "= !" in the following PHP code mean?

Tags: php, mysql

When i run the sql script and substitute it with a numbers it return empty or null

```
   $order_f = $dbs->query_field("SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE order_center_id = !", $record['cust_id']);
```

What does the = ! stand for? Is this not equal?

Comment: ! usually stands for NOT. in other words, if the value is true, it becomes false, and the opposite.

Comment: @SalmanA which is why I made a comment. so in SQL, is != and =! the same thing? actually that seems to not be the case here, since there is a space between = and !

Comment: @SkyLover that is in relation to other languages. I am not certain if it is the case for SQL

Comment: What kind of object  is `$dbs` ?

Comment: @kennypu, I think you didn't notice the space between `=` and `!`. Its two operators.

Comment: if you omit the space between the = and ! it gives you syntax error

Comment: @red $dsn = array( 'phptype'  => 'mysql', 'username' => 'my_db_user', 'password'  => 'password12', 'hostspec'  => 'localhost', 'database'  => 'super_db' ); $dbs = new database($dsn);

Comment: @SkyLover what is `database` ? Are you using any kind of Frameworks ?

Comment: @Red its MDB2 Im not the author of this db but im just resuming their works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an operator at all!

In your case it seems that the `query_field()` method that's provided by your database object (which I think is based on [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.php)) provides some kind of prepared statement, where exclamation marks are used for place holders. I'm imagining that the following query is executed based on your code:

```
SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE order_center_id = 123
```

Where `123` is the value of `$record['cust_id']`.

**Old answer**

In your case `!=` (or `<>`) *could be* the same as `=!` (or `= NOT(...)`), because "not equal to" might be considered the same as "equal to inverse of", but only for boolean value logic. It will not work when you compare strings.

Also, there's a difference in [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html):

```
a = !b & c
```

This is evaluated as `a = NOT(b) & c`.

```
a != b & c
```

Whereas this is evaluated as `a = NOT(b & c)`.

Comment: Or `!` could just be a placeholder for that `query_field` function, like `?` is for PDO. Just a random thought seeing as there's no value to compare to in that SQL string.

Comment: @Jack it gives you an error if you omit the space between = and !

Comment: @FabrícioMatté There are placeholders that have `!`? I have not heard of such a thing.

Comment: @Jack could be `preg_replace_callback`, in case that custom function would do some kind of prepared statement emulation. `:P` spencer7593's answer expands on that line of thought.

Comment: @jack, I agree. I was trying to tell that its two independent things, since you were explaining about `!=` operator.

Comment: @SkyLover Where does your `database` class come from? Did you write it yourself?

Comment: no i didnt write the original db my friend did and he just quit recently and I assume of all of his works.

Comment: @SkyLover I think the database class is based on [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.php) actually.

Comment: @Jack I see this was actually my first time working such as complex like that everything are paramaterized queries. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

**Q:** What does the = ! stand for? Is this not equal?

No. A not equals comparator would be `foo != bar`  or `foo <> bar`

I think you need to look at the `query_field` function to figure out what that's doing. It looks like the query is intended to do an equals comparison, and that exclamation point is a placeholder. (I'm not familiar with that `query_field` function; it doesn't look like a mysql_, mysqli_ or a PDO function, at least, that I've ever seen.)

What is `$dbs`? What kind of object is that? I bet that's where this method is defined.

I suspect someone has added a layer, on top of mysql interface, to pseudo-support paramaterized queries.  Likely, that second argument to the function gets run through mysql_real_escape_string, before it's included in the SQL text, replacing the bang (!). That seems the most likely explanation.

Comment: it should be a placeholder like you said, Other ways whats need of passing `cust_id` to that method.

Comment: $dsn = array(   
     'phptype'  => 'mysql', 
    'username'   => 'my_db_user',   
     'password'  => 'password12', 
     'hostspec'  => 'localhost', 
    'database'  => 'super_db' );
  
   $dbs = new database($dsn);

Comment: @SkyLover You'll have to look into the `database` class then.

Comment: don't post your password values, SkyLover!

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I will thanks a lot you guys for the time answering my question